# parsing xml with PHP simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

so i have this XML: the result of `var_dump`

```
string '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<data>
<entry key="message Type">
<![
    CDATA[
        urgent
    ]
]></entry><entry key="message Title"><![
    CDATA[
        teswt
    ]
]></entry><entry key="message Body"><![
    CDATA[
        teasd
    ]
]></entry><entry key="message Priority"><![
    CDATA[
        1
    ]
]></entry></data>
' (length=260)
```

my code looks like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($tablerow['data']);
$inputs = $xml->xpath("/schema/user_input[@type!='hidden']/input|/schema/input");
foreach($inputs as $cur_input) {

        $cur_input_name = (string)$cur_input['name'];
        $cur_input_value = $task_input_values[$cur_input_name];
        $input_name = isset($cur_input['label']) ? (string)$cur_input['label'] : $cur_input['name'];
}
        var_dump($tablerow['data']);
```

`$tablerow['data']` is the XML from the DB. any help how to get the `message Title` value from this??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath expression you are using doesn't even resemble the XML document you posted, so I don't know how you would expect to ever find the values you are looking for.  The following will extract "teswt" from your sample XML document:

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_string($tablerow['data']);
$title = '';

foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
    if ((string) $entry['key'] == 'message Title') {
        $title = (string) $entry;
        break;
    }
}

echo $title;
?>
```

**Edit:** Updated to use the SimpleXML "style" rather than XPath.

Comment: it's working but if i have 3 messages and the last two are empty it will show $title as "teswtteswtteswt"...

Comment: The code in my answer as it is currently written will only result in the text from one element being saved to `$title`.  It's possible you copied it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML should be in proper way.

Check This

```
    <?php
    $xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
            <data>
                <entry key="message Type">
                    <![CDATA[urgent]]>
                </entry>
                <entry key="message Title">
                    <![CDATA[teswt]]>
                </entry>
                <entry key="message Body">
                    <![CDATA[xxxxx]]>
                </entry>
                <entry key="message Priority">
                    <![CDATA[1]]>
                </entry>
            </data>';

    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

    foreach ($xml->entry as $entry)
    {   
       echo $entry['key']."<br/>";
    }
    ?>
```